# What are the python3 graphic options to replace old pychart

Tags: python, django, python-3.4, pychart

I am upgrading a very old project from Django 1.2 to 1.6, and Python 2.6 to Python 3.4. It has a very old graphics package called PyChart which never been updated since 2006. Of cause, it is not compatible with my current python3. What are good Python 3 graphics options to replace old PyChart? Thanks!